# Whom does the "Tochter des Drachen" kill?

Tags: askir

I have listened to all the 14 audiobooks (so I might not use the correct spellings)  many times in German, but still am totally confused about the "Tochter des Drachen"-Prophesy(TDP). The [main Prophesy](https://askir.fandom.com/de/wiki/Prophezeiungen) about Havald is spelled out pretty clearly in "Der Kronrat" but TDP is not.

TD, who is probably Leandra, but as Elsine’s and Askannon‘s Daughter might also be Serafine, is supposed to kill Kolaron, but it might also be Omagor.

As I understand it, Havald killed Kolaron(who is actually Rogamon). So is she meant to kill Omagor? In a sense, Havald has become Omagor. So, will she kill Havald?

Or is the Prophesy rendered moot by the changing of the three gods‘ plan about Leandra, after the intervention of the Nameless?

As for the "Er selbst wird es sein, der auf meiner Klinge stirbt und so die Hoffnung weiterträgt" part: has this happened by the end of "Der Wanderer"? True, he is dead-like in the temple, but due to the throat slitting, poisoning and drowning. Not due to Seelenreißer. Also, at some point it is argued that the three kind of neutralised each other, so that Mama Maerbellinae could save him.